# creating a box with a python script in 3ds max

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

When I open the scripting window with `Scripting / New script`, there's an option in the menu to change the language to python `Language / python`. I didn't know python was available in 3ds max. Is there a python interface to write regular scripts in 3dsmax? For example, this script works in maxscript:

```
mesh01 = Box()
```

Does it have a python equivalent? (it didn't work when I executed it) Or is the python interface for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
import pymxs
mesh01 = pymxs.runtime.box()
```